# Django API ignored exception in sessions module

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-contrib

I'm running a django rest framework server hosted on google cloud. Every hour or so I get a couple of these errors that I can't figure out:

> Exception ignored in: .cb at 0x7f50f275ebf8>
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): (no traceback provided)
>
> File "", line 191, in cb
>       "KeyError: ('django.contrib.sessions.serializers',)

There's no traceback since the error is caught and ignored. I've followed the code down to the cpython library in this method:

```
def _get_module_lock(name):
    """Get or create the module lock for a given module name.
    Should only be called with the import lock taken."""
    lock = None
    try:
        lock = _module_locks[name]()
    except KeyError:
        pass
    if lock is None:
        if _thread is None:
            lock = _DummyModuleLock(name)
        else:
            lock = _ModuleLock(name)
        def cb(_):
            del _module_locks[name]
        _module_locks[name] = _weakref.ref(lock, cb)
    return lock
```

Has anyone seen this error before? I can't find any pattern of when this error comes in and can't manually reproduce it with any certainty.

Comment: I have the same error except I have KeyError: 'django.db.models.sql.compiler'

Comment: When I restarted the project again the error didn't happen